# Powershell signing in AD enviroment

Tags: powershell, certificate

I got a powershell script and i wanted to distribute that to all clients.
However, it is prescribed in my company (because I am only an OU administrator) that I only distribute signed scripts.
I have full administrators rights in my OU on user and computer.
Should I create my own certificate, sign my scripts with it, and distribute it via Group Policy?
Do I have to use a certificate from the domain controller? (I have no rights for the DC.)

What should I do best and what is the easiest or the best way to do it?
Unfortunately, I have no experience with powershell certificates.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in an environment that has delegated OU administrative rights you *should* already have an internal CA already in place. You should work with the team responsible for the CA to get a code signing certificate that is already trusted organization wide.

That's a much better option versus generating and distributing your own cert - that could very well be a policy breach in a lot of organizations.